# How to get last executed query log of mongodb in node express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How to get last query log of mongodb in node express?

I need to console the last debugging query of mongo in node. Same thing we can do in php, so may I know is there any way to get last executed query in express js?

Answer (score 1):

For debugging the query logs you need to enable the logger.
if you are using mongoose client then you can use this setting.

`mongoose.set('debug', true);`